# Download button for cross-server download with counter & AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, download

I have a little PHP script that is used to serve a file cross-server : http://pastebin.com/Z1xhPxVm

This works perfectly well.

Now, what I'm trying to accomplish is to serve this file via a button click. I figure the best way to do this is to use JavaScript but have been having trouble serving the file. So far I've only been able to output the response `success: function(response)` directly into the website (garbled text).

My other code: http://pastebin.com/GAN5EDdb

and I added:

```
if ( $_POST['dl'] == true ) {
        return sendTest();
}
```

To the top of the first code I pasted.

I'm kind of new to AJAX and the like, so is there a better way to do this?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Tre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in you trying to send a php array directly to javascript. One way to accomplish this is converting the results into JSON format.

Try doing this:

PHP section:

```
return json_encode($res);
```

Javascript/JQuery section:

```
var javaArray = $.parseJSON(response);
```

Hope this helps.